# HTML5 scaling translating yields wrong position

Tags: html, canvas, matrix, transform, scale

I have the following code which helps in transforming the images on the canvas based on the values obtained via the matrix value from the gesture control in winjs.

Trial 1:

At first i tried using canvas.setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f);

```
        for (var i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
            elt[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + i);
            can.appendChild(elt[i]);

        }
       for (var i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
         var m = new MSCSSMatrix(elt[i].style.transform);
            ctx.save();             
            ctx.setTransform(m.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e, m.f);
            ctx.drawImage(can.children[i], parseInt(elt[i].style.left), parseInt(elt[i].style.top), 180, 500);
            ctx.restore();
      }
```

Trial 2:

As per many tutorials, it was suggested that scaling-rotate-translate order to be followed while transforming,so I tried this

```
      for (var i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
            elt[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + i);
            can.appendChild(elt[i]);

        }
    for (var i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
         var m = new MSCSSMatrix(elt[i].style.transform);
             ctx.save();             
             ctx.scale(Math.sqrt((m.a * m.a) + (m.c * m.c)), Math.sqrt((m.b * m.b) + (m.d * m.d)));
             ctx.rotate(Math.atan(-(m.m21) / m.m22));
             ctx.translate(m.e, m.f);
             ctx.drawImage(can.children[i], parseInt(elt[i].style.left), parseInt(elt[i].style.top), 180, 500);
             ctx.restore();
      }
```

In both cases,the transformed images which are only translated are properly positioned on the canvas .
But when the images are scaled and translated the transformed images does not appear in their right positions.So there seems to be a change in the coordinates of the image only when the image is scaled.
How do I go about to fix this!?

Comment: Can some one help me on this?